# How to select rows from table with several classes in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table:

```
<table>
<tr class="someclass"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr class="anotherclass"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr class="newclass"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr class="anotherclass"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr class="anotherclass"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr class="someclass"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr class="someclass"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr class="newclass"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr class="newclass"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

i want to add some css style (add class "colored") to rows with classes "someclass" and "anotherclass". I know how to do it for only one class:

```
$('table tr.someclass').addClass('colored');
```

But how can i select rows with 2 or more classes?

Maybe somebody will answer about using commas, but what i can do if my selection is like:

```
$ ('table tr.someclass:odd:lt(5):not(tr:first-child)').addClass('colored');
```

I want to select first 5 rows (with classes "someclass" and "anotherclass" only!) except first one, then select only odd of them, and finally add a class "colored".

Comment: jQuery uses CSS selectors, therefor... `$("selector1, selector2")` - [jQuery Learning Center -> Selecting Elements](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)

Comment: What do you mean with `for only one class` The code you posted selects the element with just the `someclass` (so with only one class)

Comment: Having a *guess* at your intention (based on the sample html provided): You have multiple options, eg `$("table tr.someclass,table.anotherclass")` `$("table").find("tr.someclass,tr.anotherclass")` `$("table tr").filter(".someclass,.anotherclass")`

Comment: See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: An alternative interpretation of your question (based on the actual question "*rows with 2 or more classes*" - ie rows that have 2 or more classes) would be `$("table tr.someclass.anotherclass")`

Comment: Note: As of jQuery 3.4, the [:odd pseudo-class](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) is deprecated. Remove it from your selectors and filter the results later using .odd() (available in jQuery 3.5.0 or newer).  Note also note that the 0-based indexing means that, counter-intuitively, :odd selects the second element, fourth element, and so on within the matched set.  So if you want the *odd* rows you need `:even` (deprecated)

Comment: For your extended requirement, use `.filter` eg  `$('table tr:odd:lt(5):not(tr:first-child)').filter('.someclass,.anotherclass')`

Comment: The $("table tr.someclass.anotherclass") will select only elements with BOTH classes, this is not a solution for me. Anyway, thanks

Comment: Sure, but that's the wording you've used in your question *rows with 2 or more classes* - ie rows that have 2 or more classes, ie that have both.  So anyone in the future looking to select *with several classes* (as in your title) *will* want to to combine both/multiple.

Comment: Thank you, freedomn-m ! My problem, finally, was in using deprecated :odd instead of new .odd().

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
$("table tr.someclass, table tr.newclass").addClass("oddcolored");
```

since the question was edited, I will edit my answer below, try using this selector for all odd ones except the first `:nth-child(2n+3)` or `:nth-child(odd):not(:first-child)` which should be combined with `:not(:nth-child(2n+7))`.. you can see things are getting quite confusing already, which means it is tume for you to change your HTML

Comment: @MarcoPerrozzi 1. That's not a comment but an answer (which shouldn't exist as such), 2. That's not how SO works. The question should contain the actual problem and not an imaginary case that is not what you're actually looking for...

Comment: This answer is what you need, he showed you how to select more then 1 element.  Just adapt it to your case and go read about jQuery selectors